# Representation of Baire 1 functions

Tags: real-analysis

Upper semi-continuous functions on the reals are Baire 1, which is readily observed by considering

$$ f_{n}(x):= \sup_{y\in [0,1]}(f(y)- n |x-y|  ) \qquad (A).$$

Indeed $f_n$ as in (A) is continuous for each natural $n$ and the pointwise limit of $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is $f$.

I am interested to know if 'explicit' representations like (A) exist for larger function classes, or even Baire 1 itself.  In particular, for a given Baire 1 function $f$, is there a formula like (A) defining a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with pointwise limit $f$?  This purported formula defining $f_n$ may of course involve constructs coming from equivalent definitions of Baire 1 (as in e.g. Baire's characterisation theorem).